# Idiomatic design to disable color in a shell script

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, colors, view

I am programming a script that presents some sort of output to the user. I would like output to be in color, but also have the option to disable it.

Example

```
$ ./run_script
Some output.  <-- pretend this text is in blue

$ ./run_script --no-color
Some output   <-- no color
```

Currently, I started programming with the [colored](https://github.com/defunkt/colored) ruby gem, so I'm doing stuff like this:

```
puts "Some output".blue
```

But now I'm starting to realize that this is a bad approach since I need some sort of functionality to disable the color.

I'm guessing a way to tackle this would be the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) where I could pass the text in the form of a hash `{:text => "Some output", :color => "blue"}` to an `Outputter` class which just masks either a `ColorOutputter` class or `NoColorOutputter` class.
Yet, I'm not quite sure as it seems almost wasterful to create three new classes for something relatively trivial. Does anyone have a better approach to resolving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did a switch on my outputter class. By switch I mean something to On/Off coloring ounput.

Creating a bunch of inherited classes for one small task in my opinion is worse than to have a switch in your outputter class (and all bad of design that you gain by using such switch)